# In Spark Streaming, is there a way to detect when a batch has finished?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, cloudera

I use Spark 1.6.0 with Cloudera 5.8.3.
I have a `DStream` object and plenty of transformations defined on top of it,

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[...](...)
val mappedStream = stream.transform { ... }.map { ... }
mappedStream.foreachRDD { ... }
mappedStream.foreachRDD { ... }
mappedStream.map { ... }.foreachRDD { ... }
```

Is there a way to register a last `foreachRDD` that is guaranteed to be executed last and only if the above `foreachRDD`s finished executing?
In other words, when the Spark UI shows that the job was complete - that's when I want to execute a lightweight function.

Is there something in the API that allows me to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondered if you could restructure the code such that all the logic performed on `mappedStream` is performed in one single foreachRDD, including the map on the last line? It's just `foreachRDD` isn't a transformation.  And a map on a DStream is equivalent to a doing a map on each rdd in foreachRDD? If that makes sense?

Comment: At the end of the day, I could probably narrow it down to a single `foreachRDD` and then the "last `foreachRDD`" would be quite simple to implement. However, I have multiple sources with different data pipelines defined for them. The implementation has a main class which reads configuration and creates sources accordingly (Kafka sources really), and each source goes through a different data pipeline - i.e., a class that defines how the stream is to be processed. I want to detect finished batches on the main class, regardless of the transformations defined in the pipeline classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using streaming listeners should solve the problem for you:

(sorry it's a java example)

```
ssc.addStreamingListener(new JobListener());

// ...

class JobListener implements StreamingListener {

 @Override
    public void onBatchCompleted(StreamingListenerBatchCompleted batchCompleted) {

        System.out.println("Batch completed, Total delay :" + batchCompleted.batchInfo().totalDelay().get().toString() +  " ms");

    }

   /*

   snipped other methods

   */


}
```

https://gist.github.com/akhld/b10dc491aad1a2007183

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-streaming/spark-streaming-streaminglisteners.html

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener

Comment: No worries. Would be interested to hear how you get on, for future reference. Only if you get a spare minute :o)

Answer (score 1):

Start a stream with name `myStreamName` and wait for it to start up -

```
deltaStreamingQuery = (streamingDF
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .queryName(myStreamName)
  .start(writePath)
)

untilStreamIsReady(myStreamName)
```

PySpark version wait for the stream to start up:

```
def getActiveStreams():
  try:
    return spark.streams.active
  except:
    print("Unable to iterate over all active streams - using an empty set instead.")
    return []

def untilStreamIsReady(name, progressions=3):
  import time
  queries = list(filter(lambda query: query.name == name, getActiveStreams()))

  while (len(queries) == 0 or len(queries[0].recentProgress) < progressions):
    time.sleep(5) # Give it a couple of seconds
    queries = list(filter(lambda query: query.name == name, getActiveStreams()))

  print("The stream {} is active and ready.".format(name))
```

Spark Scala version wait for the stream to start up:

```
def getActiveStreams():Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery] = {
  return try {
    spark.streams.active
  } catch {
    case e:Throwable => {
      // In extream cases, this funtion may throw an ignorable error.
      println("Unable to iterate over all active streams - using an empty set instead.")
      Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery]()
    }
  }
}

def untilStreamIsReady(name:String, progressions:Int = 3):Unit = {
  var queries = getActiveStreams().filter(_.name == name)

  while (queries.length == 0 || queries(0).recentProgress.length < progressions) {
    Thread.sleep(5*1000) // Give it a couple of seconds
    queries = getActiveStreams().filter(_.name == name)
  }
  println("The stream %s is active and ready.".format(name))
}
```

To the original question.. add another version of this function - wait for the stream first to start up and then wait another time (just add a negative condition on the wait state) for it to finish, so the complete version would look something like this -

```
untilStreamIsReady(myStreamName) 
untilStreamIsDone(myStreamName)   // reverse of untilStreamIsReady - wait when myStreamName will not be in the list
```