# Spark Streaming - obtain batch-level performance stats

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm setting up an `Apache Spark` cluster to perform realtime streaming computations and would like to monitor the performance of the deployment by tracking various metrics like sizes of batches, batch processing times, etc. My `Spark Streaming` program is written in `Scala`

**Questions**

1. The [Spark monitoring REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) description lists the various endpoints available. However, I couldn't find endpoints that expose batch-level info. Is there a way to get a list of all the Spark batches that have been run for an application and other per-batch details such as follows:

   - *Number of events per batch*
   - *Processing time*
   - *Scheduling delay*
   - *Exit status:* ie, whether the batch was processed successfully or not
2. In case such a batch-level API is unavailable, can batch-level stats (eg: size, processing time, scheduling delay, etc.) be obtained by adding custom instrumentation to the spark streaming program.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Regarding 2. this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980447/in-spark-streaming-is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-a-batch-has-finished/41981256#41981256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no luck with 1., this will help with 2.:

```
ssc.addStreamingListener(new JobListener());

// ...

class JobListener implements StreamingListener {

    @Override
    public void onBatchCompleted(StreamingListenerBatchCompleted batchCompleted) {

        System.out.println("Batch completed, Total delay :" + batchCompleted.batchInfo().totalDelay().get().toString() +  " ms");

    }

   /*

   snipped other methods

   */


}
```

Taken from [In Spark Streaming, is there a way to detect when a batch has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980447/in-spark-streaming-is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-a-batch-has-finished/41981256#41981256)

`batchCompleted.batchInfo()` [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/BatchInfo.html):

- `numRecords`
- `batchTime`, `processsingStartTime`, `processingEndTime`
- `schedulingDelay`
- `outputOperationInfos`

Hopefully you can get what you need from those properties.

Comment: Thanks @ImDarrenG!! If this works, it would definitely do the job for me. Once I've tested it in my code, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Just noticed you're using Scala, sorry the example I copy/pasted is java, but you hopefully get the gist of it.

Comment: That's fine. I got it. Thanks.