# StreamingListener to send metric to kafka-topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980447/in-spark-streaming-is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-a-batch-has-finished/41981256), I added the class to my application.

What I try to do is send a message to a `kafka-topic` with this:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{Callback, KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord, RecordMetadata}

class JobListener(config: Properties) extends StreamingListener {
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](config)

  override def onBatchCompleted(batchCompleted: StreamingListenerBatchCompleted): Unit = {
    val info: BatchInfo = batchCompleted.batchInfo

    val lRecord = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("a","b",batchCompleted.batchInfo().totalDelay().get().toString() +  " ms")

    producer.send(lRecord)
  }
}
```

But this fails to send any message to my topic.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: There are no exceptions. The application never fails : in local, the sending stays silent, and on the cluster, I witness the microbatches take way more time than expected but don't buffer as they would if any processing was taking more time than their duration, ie microbatches appear minutes after expectations, and it never gets better.

Comment: the code seems to be working, unless there is any issue in configs. What are the contents of config? Also, what is the kafka version you are using?
 Just to try out, can you see if removing any partitioning info helps? Just try with basic kafka server using the quick-start link provided here: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart ... If this works, we know where to hunt the problem for :)

Comment: please check your config and specifically your port, are you pointing to the kafka consumer port , instead of the zookeeper port.