# Spark structured streaming: what are the possible usages of queryName() setting?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

As per [Structured Streaming Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks)

`queryName("myTableName")` is used to defined the in-memory table name when the output sink is `format("memory")`

```
aggDF
  .writeStream
  .queryName("aggregates") // this query name will be the table name
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("memory")
  .start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show() // interactively query in-memory table
```

Spark source code for [DataStreamWriterscala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.scala#L120) documents `queryName()` as:

> Specifies the name of the [[StreamingQuery]] that can be started with `start()`.
>   This name must be unique among all the currently active queries in the associated SQLContext.

**QUESTION**: is there any other possible usages of the `queryName()` setting? Spark job logs? details in [progress monitoring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#managing-streaming-queries)  of the query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the following three usages of the `queryName`:

1. As mentioned by OP and documented in the Structured Streaming Guide it is used to define the in-memory table name when the output sink is of format "memory".
2. The queryName defines the value of `event.progress.name` where the event is a `QueryProgressEvent` within the `StreamingQueryListener`.
3. It is also used in the description column of the Spark Web UI (see screenshot where I set `queryName("StackoverflowTest")`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @mike answer, I want to mention that in Databricks (which uses Spark at its core) you can use the defined query name in conjunction with the function `untilStreamIsReady()`.

For example, if you define the streaming query `StackoverflowTest`, then you could execute the function `untilStreamIsReady('StackoverflowTest')` to wait until the query is ready and started (sorry for being Captain Obvious).

I must say I could not find a direct reference for this function in the official documentation, but found it in the following links:

- [In Spark Streaming, is there a way to detect when a batch has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980447/in-spark-streaming-is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-a-batch-has-finished)
- example of usage: https://youtu.be/KLD10xn4sX8?t=1219